# Confusing SQL Server code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if someone could help me understand what this code is doing.  I have inhereted a SQL script and I'm trying to update the code so it's easier to read.  I've looked at the below code and it seems like there's an easier way to do this, but I can't wrap my head around what this code is actually doing.  Could anyone help me just describe this code?  (Maybe clue me into how to do this with a subquery or EXISTS or an easier way to read this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.id
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
INTO #DLK_TEMP
from Inner_Source D
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Outer_Source_1 S on D.au = S.AU 
        AND D.wcv_entity_key = S.wcv_entity_key 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Outer_Source_2 F on S.id = F.id
WHERE S.id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Does it work? Yes? Don't touch it then

Comment: He wants to understand what it is doing.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that `WHERE S.id` is in the `WHERE` clause. This turns your first outer join into an inner join.

Comment: Is it intentional that you're selecting the same field three times?

Comment: And BTW, no.  The FLAG1 should be 1-3.  Basically I was showing that nothing from the Inner_Source table was being used, just in case it was important.  Sorry if that added confusion to everyone, but you nailed the answer I was looking for.  Now I can describe what this is actually doing. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems strange that it's performing an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on `S` and then testing for those rows where the join succeeds. It should be an `INNER JOIN` instead. And if `S.ID` is not nullable then you can also remove the `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.id
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
INTO #DLK_TEMP
FROM Inner_Source AS D
JOIN Outer_Source_1 AS S
    ON D.au = S.AU 
    AND D.wcv_entity_key = S.wcv_entity_key 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Outer_Source_2 AS F
ON S.id = F.id
```

If you like, you can change the first join to an `EXISTS` clause to make it clear that the join is only acting as a filter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    s.id
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
    ,f.FLAG1
INTO #DLK_TEMP
FROM Outer_Source_1 AS S
LEFT OUTER JOIN Outer_Source_2 AS F ON S.id = F.id
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM Inner_Source AS D
    WHERE D.au = S.AU 
    AND D.wcv_entity_key = S.wcv_entity_key
)
```

Comment: Since you're refactoring it, might as well remove the triple `FLAG1` field.

Comment: You guys are awesome. I just couldn't wrap my head around the 2 outer join with no columns from the table being inner joined to....

Thanks so much Mark!

Answer (score 0):

```
INTO #DLK_TEMP
```

is a temporary table (destroyed when connection is closed) that you are inserting a doubly exciting outer join into.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are better than subqueries in nearly every case because you tell the optimizer specifically what fields to join. Subqeries *can* be changed by the optimizer to joins in certain cases, where you'd get the same performance, but in others it'll be an unindexed `O(n^2)` search.

As to what it does specifically, it joins `Inner_Source` with `Outer_Source_1` and `Outer_Source_2` (outer joins specifically, meaning you get rows even if the joined fields are missing in some of the tables (although the first join is pretty much an inner join..)) and inserts a few fields from the resulting data set into the temporary table `#DLK_TEMP`.

You should read up on joins because they're a staple of database design and programming. That query of yours is really quite basic.

Answer (score 0):

This is selecting all the distinct values (`s.id`, `f.FLAG1`, `f.FLAG1`, `f.FLAG1` combined being distinct) into a temporary table called `#DLK_TEMP`. The data it is getting (i.e. `s.id`, `f.FLAG1`, `f.FLAG1`, `f.FLAG1`) is coming from three different tables that cave unique keys (`Inner_Source`, `Outer_Source_1`, `Outer_Source_2`). The left joins here providing a presendence to the values to the left-hand-side of the join statement.

*Note, Left outer joins include all of the records from the first (left) of two tables, even if there are no matching values for records in the second (right) table.*

I hope this helps.